# How do I make big constraint delimiters in an LP align nicely?

Tags: alignment

I'm trying to write an LP using \alignat, equation 2 has a lot of delimiters and the only way I could figure to make it not messy was to write those delimiters outside the aligned environment. Is there a way to continue the alignment so that 2 and 3 in the example align neatly while the delimiters are clearly formatted to show they belong to equation 2? Because there are some issues now as you can see, the equals signs don't align and the delimiters for equation 2 are not clear. Is there a better way?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}   

\begin{alignat}{4}
  \min & \sum_{\forall m \in M} \sum_{\forall t \in T} \sum_{\forall i \in C \backslash C_S} x_i^{t,m} \\
  \text{s.t.} \quad &x_i^{t,m} + U_{S^C} \left( \sum_{j \in \Gamma(i)} y_{i,j}^{t-1,m} \right) \quad     &=\quad x_i^{t-1,m} + (1-U_{R^C})E_m d_i^{t-1,m} + U_{R^C} \left( \sum_{j \in \Gamma^{-1}(i)} y_{j,i}^{t-1,m} \right)\\
\intertext{
\begin{flushright}
    $\forall i \in C; \quad \forall t \in T; \quad \forall m \in M; \quad E_1 = 1; \quad  E_2 \geq 1;$
    $U_{R^C}  = 1: i \not\in C_R; \quad U_{R^C} = 0: i \in C_R; \quad U_{S^C} = 1: i \not\in C_S; \quad U_{S^C} = 0: i \in C_S$
\end{flushright}
}
& \sum_{i \in \Gamma(i)} y_{i,j}^{t,1} - x_i^{t,1} &\leq 0 
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please extend your example to a full minimal example that others can copy and test.

Comment: Unrelated, never use `\text{min}`, this is not what the `\text` command is for. Especially when `\min` already exists.

Comment: \intertext doesn't seem to want to be used here.

Comment: You haven't shown how you used `\intertext`  so we don't know what you did. Remember `\intertext` should be a part of the alignment. I urge you to reformat whatever it is you're trying to typeset, it is **not** particularly readable as it is now

Comment: I don't know how to make this more readable other than insert a simpler equation, it seems pretty straightforward to em.

Comment: I'll try it simpler and get back to this

Comment: For example what exactly does the code in `flushright` belong to? Is it part of (4.2)? and note that your image does not match your code and I'd probably not use `paper` as a class.

Comment: Well that's kind of the point of the question, how to make it clear the part in flushright belongs to 4.2 without it being super messy. I figured this was less messy. I made the \intertext work now (apparently the alignat environment doesn't like white rules), but I still have some issues, I rephrased the question with the correct code and picture. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I changed the name of the question to better fit the content also.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution, using  the `mini!` environment, from  `optidef`, and the `\mathllap` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{4ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}{}{\mkern-20mu\sum_{m\in M}\sum_{t \in T} \sum_{i \in C \backslash C_S} x_i^{t,m}}
{\label{eq: 1}}{\tag{1}}
\addConstraint{x_i^{t,m} + u_{S^C} \Bigl( \sum_{j \in \Gamma(i)} y_{i,j}^{t-1,m} \Bigr)}
{=\begin{aligned}[t] x_i^{t-1,m} + (1-U_{R^C})E_m d_i^{t-1,m} + U_{R^C} \Bigl( \sum_{j \in \Gamma^{-1}(i)} y_{j,i}^{t-1,m}\Bigr)\\%
\forall i \in C; \quad \forall t \in T; \quad \forall m \in M; \quad E_1 = 1; \quad E_2 \geq 1;\\%
\mathllap{U_{R^C} = 1: i \not\in C_R; \quad U_{R^C} = 0: i \in C_R; \quad U_{S^C} = 1: i \not\in C_S; \quad U_{S^C} = 0: i \in C_S}
\end{aligned}}
\addConstraint{\bigstrut[t]\sum_{i \in \Gamma^(i)} y_{i,j}^{t,1}-x_i^{t,1}}{\leq 0}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I didn't notice this answer until now. Thank you so much that helps alot.

Comment: @PaulVergouwe: For optimisation problems layout,   I recommend this comparatively recent package.